# How to get valid html from the invalid?

Tags: c#, .net, html

I need a way to get valid html from invalid (i have dirty records in a database so I need to make one pass through it and process each record).

The criteria of being valid is that it could be pasted into a `<div></div>` as innerHtml. If no valid html can be made, it should be an empty string.
I need it do the same that tinyMCE does. See:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/v6baab

Example1:

`<div>hi there</span>`

Should be

`<div>hi there</div>` or `<span>hi there</span>`

Example2:

`<style> &amp;amp;amp;lt;!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face {font-family: 'Century Gothic';} --&amp;amp;gt; </style> AAAA`

Should be

`<p>AAAA</p>`

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I've tried to use HtmlAgilityPack [link](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).
But it only closes open tags and don't cut or comment incorrect.
So that in the 2nd example we got the same string.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#/.NET: " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SGMLReader: http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader